# running PIL on 64bit

Tags: python, 64-bit, python-imaging-library

Is there any way of running PIL(Python Imaging Library) on a 64bit OS?

it is windows 7 64bit

Comment: This link might help: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2009-March/005448.html

Comment: You might want to mention the OS... It compiles and works perfectly on 64-bit unix-y OS-es.  I have no idea about 64-bit windows, though...

Comment: The Win32 version works for me on Win 7 64-bit. PIL v1.1.7, Python 2.6.4, and Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600].

Comment: ditto jtpresta. I haven't had any problems with that setup either.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

PIL-1.1.7.win-amd64-py2.x installers are available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil

Comment: What if I have python 3.3?